# Pending Migration Error | Cannot Remove Dupe Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I am trying to run a rails server and am coming across this error:

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

The DB in question is currently empty so no worries of losing data. When I run the code:

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

`RAILS_ENV=development rake db:migrate`

`rake db:migrate`

**I am returned the error:**

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError: 

Multiple migrations have the name CreatePosts


Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**When running the server, this is returned to my terminal:**

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-09-22 11:30:34 -0400

ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

):
```

And finally, running `rake db:migrate:status` returns:

```
Schema migrations table does not exist yet.
```

What could possibly be going on? Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

Output of `migrate:status` after `bin/rake` command

```
 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20150922142819  Devise create users
   up     20150922143253  Create posts
  down    20150922143414  Create posts
  down    20150922145906  Acts as votable migration
  down    20150922150209  Create comments
  down    20150922151035  Acts as follower migration
```

Comment: I guess there are duplicate migration files in your project, can you show us  the migrations directory files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create the database schema/structure before you run migrations. `db:schema:load` will do this for you:

```
bin/rake db:schema:load
```

As for the error "Multiple migrations have the name CreatePosts" - it's as it says. Look in the contents your `db/migrate` folder for two files that have the same name `class CreatePosts` within the files - they should be named differently, or the second one should be removed if they are duplicates.

Comment: used the `bin/rake` command, updated question to show output of that.

Comment: @ether `bin/rake` != `bin/rake db:schema:load` - you said your database was empty, you must load it.

Comment: I did use the entire code, was just referring to it as `bin/rake`

Comment: @ether Yet the output you're showing isn't of a `db:schema:load` command. Should I still be waiting for it?

Comment: my mistake, I meant that is the output of the migrate:status after using the `db:schema:load` it is registering the DB now

Comment: @ether Good! Now you must address the duplicate. Once you do that, the rest of the migrations will run perfectly fine. Be aware that if you deleted the wrong duplicate (in this case, the file starting with `20150922143253`) - then it will try to migrate a command that you've already done, and still fail, probably an error to the tune of "table already exists." You should manually revert the change in the migration, or update the migration file to the timestamp I mentioned in this comment.

Comment: After removing the Dupe from the *migrate* folder, I ran `rake db:migrate` once more and it finished migrating the files with the `down` status. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have more than one migration with the same name. This is not allowed. If your database is empty, no tables, the best plan is to rename the second one so they don't conflict any more.

Obviously the filenames are unique, but each migration file defines a class, and these classes must be unique as well, plus should match the filename.

Having `201509201949343_create_posts` and `201509220293910_create_posts` would be a typical conflict here.

You may want to investigate how this came to pass, as having your development schema diverge from the production one is generally a bad idea. Once you resolve the conflict locally, try and update the schema tracking table on production accordingly.

Comment: I think I may have duped them when creating, could I safely just remove the second one?

Comment: The first thing to establish is if they're identical or if they're coincidentally the same name. Search for `CreatePosts` in your migration files and you'll find them quickly enough.

Comment: They were identical and I removed the dupe. I still have 3 migrations with the status of `down`?

Comment: Are you talking about a from-scratch migration, no tables at all, or against an existing schema? What do you mean by status? `rake db:migrate` should bring you up.